# How to pass additional parameters in next-auth social login in NextJs?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I need to pass additional parameters to `signIn` function using [next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org/) in a NextJs project.

Here is what I tried.

```
<button
    onClick={() =>
    signIn(providers.facebook.id, { userType: "customer" })
    }
>
    <img src="images/facebook.svg" className="w-5 h-5" />
</button>
```

`[...nextAuth].js` code

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import dbConnect from "../../../lib/dbConnect";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import User from "../../../models/User";
import brcypt from "bcryptjs";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";
import InstagramProvider from "next-auth/providers/instagram";


dbConnect();


export default NextAuth({
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,

  //The providers are the authentication method
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      // The name to display on the sign in form (e.g. 'Sign in with...')
      name: "Credentials",
      // The credentials is used to generate a suitable form on the sign in page.
      // You can specify whatever fields you are expecting to be submitted.
      // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
      // You can pass any HTML attribute to the <input> tag through the object.
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        try {
          const email = credentials.email;
          const password = credentials.password;

          const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });

          if (!user) {
            return null;
          }
          if (user) {
            let allow = await signInUser({ password, user });

            if (allow == true) {
              return user;
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          }
        } catch (error) {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorizationUrl:
        "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?prompt=consent&access_type=offline&response_type=code",
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          userType: "customer" || "admin",
        },
      },
    }),
    InstagramProvider({
      clientId: process.env.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  database: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
  callbacks: {
    async jwt(token, profile) {
      console.log("jwt token>>>>", token);
      console.log("jwt profile>>>>", profile);

      return token;
    },

    async session({ session, user, token }) {

      if (token) {
        const name = token.token.user.name;
        const email = token.token.user.email;
        const image = token.token.user.image;
        const platform = token.token.account.provider;
        handleUser(name, email, image, platform);
      }

      return token.token.token;
    },
  },
});



const signInUser = async ({ password, user }) => {
  let allow = true;

  if (!password) {
    allow = false;
  }

  const isMatch = await brcypt.compare(password, user.password);

  if (!isMatch) {
    allow = false;
  }

  return allow;
};


async function handleUser(name, email, image, platform) {
  
  console.log("Handle User>>>>>", name);
  console.log("Handle email>>>>>", email);
  console.log("Handle image>>>>>", image);
  console.log("Handle platform>>>>>", platform);
  
}
```

Inside the `callbacks` function I tried logging `token` & `profile`. The additional params I passed is not being sent.

What is the right way to achieve this in Next.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can find an article on the GitHub discussion section for next-auth [here](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/4094). The general gist of the answer is that you specify additional custom parameters in the Google Provider parameter (as below). There are other steps, but overall they appear to have solved it. Hope this helps.

```
GoogleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        authorization: {
          params: {
            prompt: "consent",
            access_type: "offline",
            response_type: "code",
            userType: "user" || "admin",  <-- THIS ONE
          },
        },
      }),
```

Comment: This is not a good solution - More info here https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/4094#discussioncomment-2699694